# An example of sufficient statistic and how to understand it.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, sufficient-statistics

I am learning sufficient statistics, and the general idea seems to be straightforward but it turns out to be really confusing when I take a closer look (and it is probably because of the conditional probability). The big picture is that, for a specific family of distribution, a sufficient statistic contains all the information about a corresponding parameter the observed data provides. Let's consider $X_1$ and $X_2 \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim}$Poi($\lambda$) with an unknown $\lambda$. One can show that:
$$P(X_1 = x_1 | X_1 + X_2 = t) = \binom{t}{x_1}\dfrac{1}{2^{x_1}} \dfrac{1}{2^{t-x_1}}$$
so $X_1 + X_2$ is a sufficient statistic by definition. This is a good and concrete example but I am still confused with some details.

1. In terms of estimating the parameter $\lambda$, it makes sense to say that $X_1$ is insufficient because both $X_1$ and $\frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}$ are unbiased estimators but the second one has smaller variance so that it contains less uncertainty and then more information about the true parameter. Is this a correct intuition?
2. From (1), we know $X_1 + X_2$ contains more information, but I don't see why it contains all the information about $\lambda$. Clearly, once we know the sum, we know the conditional distribution, which is a binomial distribution in this case. Is this what "contains all the information" means since we can generate the exact same data based on the statistic without knowing anything about the parameter?
3. I don't see how "contains all the information" is helpful for the inference of the true parameter. In this example, the conditional distribution is not even a Poisson distribution, so I don't know why it helps with the inference.

Comment: Regarding 1), A statistic is a function of the data, it need not be an estimator. Regarding 3), perhaps the best way to get intuition for this notion is to see how it can be used to perform inference. In particular, whatever text you are reading should provide theorems concerning sufficient statistics. I agree that sufficiency is confusing. It does seem that some of the definitions are rather arbitrary and unmotivated. See Lehmann's note on complete statistics.

Comment: You are not trying to estimate $\lambda$ with a sufficient statistic. You are trying to replace it. Going back to the definition, $T(X_1, X_2)$ is sufficient if the distribution of $X_1, X_2 \ | \ T(X_1, X_2) = t$ does not depend on $\lambda$. So you have replaced the need for $\lambda$ when working with $X_1, X_2$ as long as you have $T$.

Comment: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~rgmartin/Teaching/Stat411/Refs/Lehmann1981.pdf

Comment: "Statistical Inference" by Casella and Berger has a very good explanation of Sufficiency